# Rich Inspect Discovery

Tags: python, rich

Im trying to dig into the Rich inpsect further to understand how it is doing the following.

If I look at an object (`result`) like so. I can see that it has the following attributes and methods.

```
>>> vars(result)
{'name': 'hello_world'}
>>> print(dir(result))
[
    '__class__',
    '__class_getitem__',
    '__contains__',
    '__delattr__',
    '__delitem__',
    '__dict__',
    '__dir__',
    '__doc__',
    '__eq__',
    '__format__',
    '__ge__',
    '__getattribute__',
    '__getitem__',
    '__gt__',
    '__hash__',
    '__init__',
    '__init_subclass__',
    '__iter__',
    '__le__',
    '__len__',
    '__lt__',
    '__module__',
    '__ne__',
    '__new__',
    '__orig_bases__',
    '__parameters__',
    '__reduce__',
    '__reduce_ex__',
    '__repr__',
    '__reversed__',
    '__setattr__',
    '__setitem__',
    '__sizeof__',
    '__slots__',
    '__str__',
    '__subclasshook__',
    '__weakref__',
    '_is_protocol',
    'clear',
    'copy',
    'failed',
    'failed_hosts',
    'fromkeys',
    'get',
    'items',
    'keys',
    'name',
    'pop',
    'popitem',
    'raise_on_error',
    'setdefault',
    'update',
    'values'
]
```

If I look at the output of Rich like so:

```
>>> inspect(result)
╭─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── <class 'nornir.core.task.AggregatedResult'> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ It basically is a dict-like object that aggregates the results for all devices.                                                                                                                            │
│ You can access each individual result by doing ``my_aggr_result["hostname_of_device"]``.                                                                                                                   │
│                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
│ ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│ │ AggregatedResult (hello_world): {'spine1-nxos': MultiResult: [Result: "hello_world", Result: "ABC1", Result: "ABC1a", Result: "ABC1b"], 'spine2-nxos': MultiResult: [Result: "hello_world", Result:    │ │
│ │ "ABC1", Result: "ABC1a", Result: "ABC1b"]}                                                                                                                                                             │ │
│ ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
│                                                                                                                                                                                                            │
│       failed = False                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│ failed_hosts = {}                                                                                                                                                                                          │
│         name = 'hello_world'                                                                                                                                                                               │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

I see that it has correctly only shown be the attributes and methods of interest.
Can anyone point to me how Rich determines what to print?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nice thing about open-source code is that you can just go find the source and read it. For this question, you'll be interested in [this file](https://github.com/Textualize/rich/blob/master/rich/_inspect.py) in the `rich` source code. You're mostly interested in the `_render` method, though some things are set up in `__init__`.

We can break down the output you were seeing, to properly understand it:

```
╭─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── <class 'nornir.core.task.AggregatedResult'> ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
```

The top line contains the "title" of the object being inspected. In this case, it's the repr of the class of the object.

```
│ It basically is a dict-like object that aggregates the results for all devices.                                                                                                                            │
│ You can access each individual result by doing ``my_aggr_result["hostname_of_device"]``.                                                                                                                   │
```

This is the docstring of the object.

```
│ ╭────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│ │ AggregatedResult (hello_world): {'spine1-nxos': MultiResult: [Result: "hello_world", Result: "ABC1", Result: "ABC1a", Result: "ABC1b"], 'spine2-nxos': MultiResult: [Result: "hello_world", Result:    │ │
│ │ "ABC1", Result: "ABC1a", Result: "ABC1b"]}                                                                                                                                                             │ │
│ ╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯ │
```

This is the pretty-printed "value" of the object. It's probably based on the object's own `repr`, but I've not dived too deeply into how `rich.pretty.Pretty` works, so there might be more to it.

```
│       failed = False                                                                                                                                                                                       │
│ failed_hosts = {}                                                                                                                                                                                          │
│         name = 'hello_world'                                                                                                                                                                               │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

The rest of the output is a list of attributes and their values. By default, only the non-callable, non-`_private`, non-`__dunder__` attributes will be listed, but you could get a more complete list with different arguments to `inspect`.

Comment: Appreciate the help. Thanks.